# Android webview Javascript function context

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I've got html file with script inside.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    var displayAlert = function() {
        alert("Start");
    };  
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I load it to webView (`webView.loadUrl(path_to_html_file)`). But when i try to call function displayAlert by
    `webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){displayAlert()})();");`
it cannot find displayAlert function. I suppose the reason is displayAlert is not global. Is there any way to achieve it without making displayAlert global. (pass context to or reference etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
$(function(){
    var displayAlert = function() {
       alert("Start");
    };  
 });
```